# How to let a sound play once in Processing?

Tags: java, audio, arduino, processing

```
import processing.serial.*;
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile file;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
//String antwoord = "A";
void setup()
{
  size(300,300);
  // I know that the first port in the serial list on my mac
  // is Serial.list()[0].
  // On Windows machines, this generally opens COM1.
  // Open whatever port is the one you're using.
  String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
  val = trim( myPort.readStringUntil(ENTER) );
       // read it and store it in val
  } 
//println(val); //print it out in the console
file = new SoundFile(this,"Promise.mp3");

if ("A".equals(val) == true && file.isPlaying() == false) {
 

file.play();
file.amp(0.2);}

else{
 ellipse(40,40,40,40);
}
}
```

I got this code, but I want the sound to keep playing as long as the signal 'A' is given. Now it starts playing constantly, which leads to a weird static noise. How can I make it just play steadidly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `SoundFile` in every run of `draw`. So `file.isPlaying()` will always return `false`.  Only create a new `SoundFile` if you haven't already. The simplest solution is probably to move `file = new SoundFile(this,"Promise.mp3");` into `setup`

Or you check or remember if you already loaded the file.

Comment: And if I were to use an if to make it pause again? How would I do that? Because then it keeps pausing?

Comment: when do you want to pause it? at the moment you don't even manage to properly play it because you immediatly load and play it again

Comment: Alright then I guess I have to work around it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if it is a bit disconnected but I recommend using minim or a different sound library instead of the processing one, since it causes a lot of problems in exporting (at least it had done so consistently for me).